# Compile Spark-3.2.0 source code ERROR Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first)

Tags: apache-spark, compiler-errors

When I run `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.3 -DskipTests clean package -e`, it will report the following error:

```
[ERROR] [Error] /home/marvel/sh/src/software/codeSrc/spark-3.2.0/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/security/HadoopDelegationTokenManagerSuite.scala:145: method reset in class UserGroupInformation cannot be accessed in object org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
[ERROR] one error found

[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. FAILURE [01:40 min]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Local Library ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Kafka 0.10+ Token Provider for Streaming ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Kafka 0.10+ Source for Structured Streaming ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 Assembly .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Avro ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-26T10:31:29+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.12: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:testCompile failed.: CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.12: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:testCompile failed.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :spark-core_2.12
```

First time dealing with this, not sure how to handle it. This is running on Ubuntu on VMware 20.04 and with the following:

- hadoop-2.7.3
- spark-3.2.0
- scala-2.12.18
- maven-3.6.3